# Conditionally expanding an Object recursively (nested children)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, svelte

**The goal of this is to have comments with recursive child comments.**

As example data for this, there are posts and comments that got fetched.

```js
let posts = [
    { id: '001a', topic: 'post topic', content: 'post content' }
]
let comments = [
    { id: '002a', postParent: '001a', directParent: '001a', content: 'comment on post' },
    { id: '003a', postParent: '001a', directParent: '002a', content: 'comment on comment' },
    { id: '004a', postParent: '001a', directParent: '003a', content: 'comment on comments comment' },
]
```

If I should formulate it into words, I would say: conditionally on a comment-objects parent-key, this object should become a child-comment-object of its parent-comment-object.
To achieve this, I came to think that it needs a functionality to create another array. Like:

```js
let postComments = [
    {
        id: '002a',
        postParent: '001a',
        directParent: '001a',
        content: 'comment on post',
        children: [
            { 
                id: '003a', 
                postParent: '001a', 
                directParent: '002a', 
                content: 'comment on comment',
                children: [ {id: '004a', post: '001a', parent: '003a', content: 'comment on comments comment' }} ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

The approach I tried until now, was solving this without creating such a new array that extends itself.
I tried outputting the comments conditionally on it's parent in an each-block. Unfortunately this didn't leadt to a scalable solution (/ to do it recursively -*I'm not sure about the right terminology here*).
That's how I got to the approach this question is now about and how to create a new array like shown in the example.

But as I'm still not sure if it's a good solution when having such data, any suggestion on a proven approach for such a problem is very welcome.

---

Edit:
I was thankfully able to create an extensive REPL from the provided answers. Unfortunately, it was overwritten while viewing and saving another REPL. The link I had posted here is now misleading, so I'll delete it and re-add it after finding the time for a recreation.The little takeaway is to make a backup of svelte REPLs if some work went into it. Which I didn't. Anyway, the answers below hold good examples as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution with no recursive function. It uses map-lookup.

```js
let posts = [
    { id: '001a', topic: 'post topic', content: 'post content' }
]
let comments = [
    { id: '002a', post: '001a', parent: '001a', content: 'comment on post' },
    { id: '003a', post: '001a', parent: '002a', content: 'comment on comment' },
    { id: '004a', post: '001a', parent: '003a', content: 'comment on comments comment' }
]

let postComments = toNestedComments(comments, posts[0].id);
console.log(postComments);

function toNestedComments(comments, postId) {
    const nestedComments = [];
    const map = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
        map[comments[i].id] = i;
    }

    for (let comment of comments) {
        if (comment.parent === postId) {
            nestedComments.push(comment);
        } else {
            if (!comments[map[comment.parent]].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
                comments[map[comment.parent]].children = [];
            }
            comments[map[comment.parent]].children.push(comment);
        }
    }

    return nestedComments;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let posts = [{ id: '001a', topic: 'post topic', content: 'post content' }]
let comments = [
  { id: '002a', post: '001a', parent: '001a', content: 'comment on post' },
  { id: '003a', post: '001a', parent: '002a', content: 'comment on comment' },
  { id: '004a', post: '001a', parent: '003a', content: 'comment on comments comment' },
]

function getNestedComments(parentId) {
  const subComments = comments.filter((c) => c.parent === parentId)
  if (subComments.length === 0) return subComments
  subComments.forEach(c => {
    c.children = getNestedComments(c.id)
  })
  return subComments
}

let postComments = getNestedComments('001a')
console.log(postComments)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBADg9gzmOEC8EDaBvCBLAJgLggHIAGEgRgEMiAaCMGKbAY0KNgXsZdomZgB2YEELYdI-ISLBEIAXwC6AKFASYAW3XSkqNEogQseNmQBM1OuJMUL0SgCdp1qr0nDRxfpukRB0eDLyNPqGOATEZADMtlYRNrxQDk5x5q6C7mBsXlpCvgJ8GjmBcsEGGCEGxnEALBYV-gjOdQYGiY4epCTRtPVuyUTZPn6DQkgjMqVBSspKYACeUCAQAMKF2ij0CyAwAGYF3qOzWxAAciAIILirB4gbK2ujEABkhswAFtjAuO2EZxdXD0QcjQMx2AFcBMwwNg-ABzcB-YQAm5wAAUbWkAElwgh7NgBLCAJSGEKSThwMEAI2uRSQG3GcAAdDtPsJ7KjUcxicgAHx8RkY3LIYV2dpgbGExnqShQTkoPmo8otCCM1XMSYGd6fb4iQggiCUJCIy407QhOSEwkhbB7VEU6mApmgAlgN4oEUkYmOMBg%20z5e2mw4GAOO5kwewAUUo7zlvJJyuYjK1X3aG3hYGNyNpnMZeCtBgtIW9vv9VMDiCUciUKnADTA5Z0EHTmYbqM6qStZJgoEZwBgsPRAQbhKAA)

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving the comments belonging to a specific parent only when you render that parent seems to me inefficient since each time you try to render the code will run through *all* your comments to find the ones belonging to that parent.

A better approach (in my opinion) is to add a property `children` to each posts/comment and populate it, as you have in your code.  The difficulty here is to do this in way to minimize the number of times you have to 'loop' over all data.

One way is to build a lookup table for each post and comment like this:

```js
const lookup = [...posts, ...comments].reduce((pre, cur) => {
  cur.children = []; // Prepares an array to hold the children
  pre[cur.id] = cur;
  return pre;
}, {});
```

And then loop over the comments again, adding themselves to the parent we can read from the lookup table.

```js
comments.forEach(c => lookup[c.parent].children.push(c));
```

Because of how javascript works in regards to objects, this will result in the items of the original `posts` and `comments` now having a `children` property populated with the comments for that element (and these comments having their own children).

Now you can recursively render these with a `Post` component and `svelte:self`.

```html
{#each children as child}
  <svelte:self {...child} />
{/each}
```

This solution only goes twice through the data to build this construction (once to make the lookup table, once to attach the comments) so is more efficient than searching the comments during render itself.

**If** your data is sorted in a way that a comment will **always** appear after it's parent, you could make this even better by pushing to the parent's children at the same time you build the map:

```js
let map = [...posts, ...comments].reduce((pre, cur) => {
  cur.children = [];
  pre[cur.id] = cur;
  if (cur.parent) pre[cur.parent].children.push(cur);
  return pre;
}, {});
```

---

**edit to fit with the data provided in the snippet**

```js
const lookup = [...posts].reduce((pre, cur) => {
  // Either a post or a comment
  const item = cur.post ?? cur.comment;
  // Prepares an array to hold the children
  item.children = []; 
  pre[cur.publicKey] = item;
  return pre;
}, {});
    
comments.forEach(({ comment }) => lookup[comment.post].children.push(comment));
```

Not perfect, but a start to get an idea.  This will put all comments on the *post* so comments do not have their own children.

[Demo Repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/8b880fb08a9442f3b8e6edaec7743b82?version=3.48.0)

Comment: Looks like a nice solution, and it was the first I tried to use. Couldn't make it work, unfortunately. I thought for the reason, that in the actual code the `id`key lives in an object outside the comment and should match the `post`key which lives inside the comment.(e.g., snippet). So I tried to adapt it to these circumstances for a while. Then I came back to try it just with the simple example from the question in a REPL and to build it up from there. But also here I couldn't make it work. Also, one question that came up is where is the `post` key in your solution and how it gets processed?

Comment: Where it concerns the `post` key it depends a bit on what end structure you have, should the comments nest into each other (as I did) or should they all be direct children of the actual post (similar to how it is here on StackOverflow).  If you want them to be 'flat', use the `post` key to find the parent they belong to instead of the `parent` key. The name parent might have been confusing here.

Comment: Not sure with the id, it feels a bit strange to me that the id of an item doesn't live with the item.  But if I look at your snippet I see that each item consist of two props: a `publicKey` and a `comment` or `post`, if you treat the two together as one object it should be doable to fetch a key, although I would preprocess that data (preferable on the server that provides it) to be more flat and just have a single object with the id baked in.

Comment: Okay nice, in terms of the `post` key it is just right, thank you . Also, working with @Mihails answer helped to understand that. I thought I'll come back to your solution at a later date and can make it work when I have a better understanding. But if it's somehow possible for you to paste the solution for the simple example in the question into a working REPL that would be marvelous and probably solve everything this question aims to find out.

In terms of preprocessing, it's data that comes from a blockchain, prepossessing is probably not possible here.

Comment: Made a REPL that should closely fit the data as you have it there. And added the code to the example for completeness.